# C# Changing a constant

Tags: c#

I have inherited a small windows form based program written in C# that uses a 'constant' (See below), I need to modify this program so 'PROPERTY_NAME' can be "jobs" and "careers".

```
    private const string PROPERTY_NAME = "jobs";
```

I'm guessing a constant isn't designed to change so should I need to change this. The line above is set once at the top of a class file and then PROPERTY_NAME is used throughout that file.

On the main form I would like to add two radio buttons 1 called 'jobs' and one called 'careers' and then change the PROPERTY_NAME in the class file based on which is selected. Would I need to pass the radio button status to the method in the class file? I recall reading that I can't simply read the radio button value from the class file.

Many thanks for your advice.

Jane

Comment: Contradiction. Constant and change does not go together, EVER!

Answer (score 7):

My best (and simplest) guess (I could elaborate into cleaner things but this is just for speed) without seeing any other part of the code would be to remove the `const` and add `readonly` so `PROPERTY_NAME` is just a plain old class member variable that cannot change outside of the constructor.

In the class's constructor, take in a string parameter, and have the code that creates an instance of this class pass in either "jobs" or "careers" (coming from the selected radio button probably) and set the `PROPERTY_NAME` variable.

**EDIT:**

Like Sasha says, another way would be using an `enum` but it depends what exactly is being done with `PROPERTY_NAME` as to whether this is appropriate for your application.

Comment: Yup I agree you can create a normal enum or just a string property and assign the value either job or career and use that string in your source code..

Answer (score 4):

If the quantity you are representing changes *ever* throughout the history of the universe then do not make it a constant. Constants are things like the number of eggs in a dozen or the atomic weight of lead.  Things like version numbers or the current price of gold change over time and therefore are not *constant*.  *Only make actually constant values into constant fields.* The compiler will treat constant fields as constant for all time, which can introduce semantic errors if they change.

Answer (score 3):

make an enum (my preferred way) and make it a readonly property. Set this property in the constructor. It isn't changeable after creation and should do what you need.

-sa

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make constant having two values. It looks like that you need to make a field storing current property name and use it allover your form. And you will be able to init such field from the radio button.